# How to find all unique values of arrays of integers where the array length and maximum integer value are set

Tags: arrays, haskell, math

I am trying to write a function which generates all unique combinations of arrays for values up to a certain number.

The function has two parameters, one parameter is the length of the array and the other is the maximum size of the integer.

`F(4, 3)` is a function that will generate all possible unique combinations of positive integers less than or equal to 4 in a three integer array. `F(10, 100)` will generate all possible unique combinations of positive integers less than or equal to 10 in a 100 integer array.

The result for `F(4, 3)` would start like this:

`(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 4), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2) ... (4, 4, 4)`

`F(10, 10)` would start like this:

`(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), ... 
 (10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)`

Comment: You second example does not look correct, since `i` and `j` are always the same. Furthermore it is not clear to me what to do in case the limit is less than the number of elements: which elements should be generated in that case? The smallest lexicographically?

Comment: Are you *sure* "Cartesian product" is the right term for what you want? I can't match my understanding of "Cartesian product" with your input/output examples. (I also can't understand the logic behind your input/output examples.)

Comment: In your second example the tuples are still size 2, not 100.

Comment: Why are the values wrapped in a 2-tuple? If the length depends on a parameter, normally this should be a list.

Comment: What do you mean "by fixed array size of 2"?

Comment: `f x y = replicateM y [1 .. x]`

Comment: I wrote the question while still thinking about it and therefore made a load of mistakes, I've now re-written the question and believe it is all there.

Comment: Thanks for the improved example

Comment: Can you clarify your meaning of "array"? Your example is a three integer tuple, but you called it an array? Just wonderin' cuz tuples, arrays, and lists have very different meanings in Haskell. i.e. `[i,j,k]` is not the same as `(i,j,k)`

Comment: @DavOS - I don't think it really matters which one is used, but I meant array with my C# hat on - a list, a collection, something I can later iterate over and that's it. Can you think of a reason this might matter? I'd be interested to know!

Comment: StackOverflow is not a service to get people to write your code - it's a way to ask for help with a specific problem. Can you provide an example of what you've already tried, and why it isn't working?

Comment: @IsaacvanBakel - I originally provided my attempt of a solution by framing the question from where I was but found this led to too much confusion (there were almost 15 more comments than what you're seeing now).

Answer (score 0):

There are `P=Max**Len` arrays for `F(Max, Len)`, and there is bijection between numbers in range `0..P-1` and arrays.

So you can just walk  in the loop through all numbers in that range and represent loop counter in M-ric numeral system (counter 4(dec) corresponds to (1, 2, 1) in your first example)

Alternate way - use array as multidigit counter (like old electrical meter display with rotating cylinders). When some digit becomes Max and should be incremented, it is reset to 1 and the next digit is incremented (`(1, 1, 4) => (1, 2, 1)` in your example).